# Do any characters from the main series of "Attack on Titan" appear in "Before the Fall"?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I just started reading *Attack on Titan: Before the Fall* and just had an urge to know whether there is any known face in the series with our current main series.

Does anyone appear in *Before the Fall*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is none.

*Before the Fall* is set [decades](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:30782) before the main *Attack on Titan* series. Even if some of the older characters in the main series were already born during this time, they were not deemed significant enough to be depicted in the story yet since *they made no appearances and the story is mainly focused on Kuklo and his time with the Survey Corps*.

Comment: Thanks for telling. I already read every chapter and wanted to know whether I missed someone !!